# Get value from view to controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m new in angular.Here is my code :

home.html :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datab track by $index">
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item" ng-click="singlegolf(la)" ng-model="la">{{data.href}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And i would like in my console log to display the value of {{data.href}} in my console So i try that in my controller :

```
$scope.singlegolf = function(la){

  console.log(la)
}
```

But this is not working can someone help me pls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datab track by $index">
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item" ng-click="singlegolf(data.href)" ng-model="la">{{data.href}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was easy^^ and it s now working :)